# how to exclude match from regex in result

Tags: regex, preg-replace, pcre

i have this simple dumy text

```
<base href="http://wjbty.lc/"/?
<a href="common/home" />
<a href="common/home" />
<a href="/common/home" />
<a href="http://common/home" />
<a href="https://common/home" />
<a href="common/home" />
```

and my regex patterns is `(?:(href="))(?!\/)(?!https:\/\/)(?!http:\/\/)(.*)"`

and its works fine and matching all relative links, but it always include `href="` in resulting match.

and how do i exclude `href="` from results.
can anyone test it and then answer please, because there two answers but none of them is working.

[image: Output in regex buddy]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your expression you have an extra set of brackets

```
(?:(href="))
```

it should be

```
(?:href=")
```

EDIT:
I think you want this

```
/(?:href=")(?!\/)(?!https:\/\/)(?!http:\/\/)(.*)"/
```

So it also doesn't capture the close quotes.
Also remember preg_match_all returns an array or arrays
The first array set is the total capture.
The second array set is the group capture (what you want)

Extra Parameter

The flags parameter can be PREG_PATTERN_ORDER or PREG_SET_ORDER

PREG_PATTERN_ORDER means array[0] will be all the capture information, while array[1] will be the information you captured in the brackets.

PREG_SET_ORDER means there will be an array element for each match, match[0] being the total information, match[1] being the capture group.

Comment: sorry Strings but this match nothing.

Comment: it works perfectly here http://wiki.jalakai.co.uk/include/preg.php and it is well formed

Comment: Got it. Strings, thanks.... your answer is helpfull to me. but you know how this submatches can be show in regexbuggy

Comment: ok no problem and i got to show submatches in rugexbuddy, again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An other way to proceed is to use the `\K` feature to exclude the substring matched by the begining of the pattern (until the `\K`) from match result. Example:

```
\shref="\K(?!(?:https?:/)?/)[^"]+
```

Advise: if you use a slash as pattern delimiter you must escape the slashes in the pattern, but it is a better choice to use an other character, for example `~`.

Note that you don't need capturing group at all, since what you want to obtain is the whole match.

If you need it you can add a lookahead at the end of the pattern to check the presence of the closing double quote: `(?=")`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use lookaheads and look behinds, this should be your answer:

```
(?<=href=")(?!\/)(?!https:\/\/)(?!http:\/\/)(.*)(?=\")
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/gS8iR6